# How Recycler View Holder.ItemView recycle

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

In my case , I got Exception

```
if (holder.isScrap() || holder.itemView.getParent() != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Scrapped or attached views may not be recycled. isScrap:"
                            + holder.isScrap() + " isAttached:"
                            + (holder.itemView.getParent() != null));
        }
```

and `holder.itemView.getParent() == true`.

I do not use `android:animateLayoutChanges` and I donn't want use "setHasStableIds(true)" , but I don't know why holder.itemView.getParent is true. Maybe someone can give me a solution or a link, thx